# How to use Segoe UI symbol in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, fonts, symbols

Seems like an easy one, but I can't figure out how to do/use [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx#scroll_bar_arrows) symbols.  I want to use a U+E135 symbol and I can't figure out how to do it.  Can someone give me a TextBlock example and also explain how I go about getting the hex equivalent to use in XAML.  Thanks.

Comment: A complete cheat sheet for the #Segoe MDL2 #Asset font tool with syntax https://youtu.be/jzrfPu82wm4

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/9c5085f7-9db7-468b-853c-9a2ff543f2d7/) forums:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xE26E;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol">
```

The trick is to replace `U+1234` with `&#x1234;`. The latter is an [XML character entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Your platform must support this font in order for this to work.

Comment: I just get a rectangle for this.

Comment: Yep, doesn't work here neighter. Is this for Windows 8 only? Because I believe the enum wich simplifies the codes does only work in W8.1+ as msdn says: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx

Comment: Here's a nice reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx (technically for the _Segoe MDL2 Assets_ typeface).

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Please use `Segoe MDL2 Assets` for `FontFamily` instead of `Segoe UI Symbol`. And it should work. Please let me know if you still have an issue.